# not able to declare variable as TVP type in Stored Proc

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

I have created a TVP and I am trying to use it in a stored proc for my input into stored proc.
the issue is I am not able to create my SP with it. Its says

```
Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure uspGetUsersPresentCount, Line 14
Must declare the scalar variable "@usersList".
```

My SP is

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'uspGetUsersPresentCount')
    BEGIN
        DROP  Procedure  [AMProcedures].[uspGetUsersPresentCount]
    END

GO


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO 

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROC [AMProcedures].[uspGetUsersPresentCount]
(
    @usersList AS [AMProcedures].[udfUserListTVP] READONLY,
    @startDate DATETIME,
    @endDate DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @okStatus TINYINT = 4
SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT MIMO.UserID, COUNT(MIMO.MoveInTime) FROM AMTables.tblUserMoveInMoveOutDetails MIMO
        JOIN @usersList ON MIMO.UserID=@usersList.UserID
            WHERE MIMO.Status=@okStatus AND
                MIMO.MoveInTime BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
            GROUP BY MIMO.UserID

SET NOCOUNT OFF

END
GO
```

can anyone tell me what wrong am I doing ...I have tried what I knew, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use an alias for the user list, or put it in square braces:

```
JOIN @usersList UL ON MIMO.UserID=UL.UserID
```

or

```
JOIN @usersList ON MIMO.UserID=[@usersList].UserID
```

Comment: I would like to know the reason why it is required to create an alias, is it something because I am using joins, as I have used TVPs as lot in sub queries without creating an alias.

Comment: This "issue" is not specific to TVPs, but to any table variable. As with normal tables, if two column names are ambigious they need to be qualified either by the table identifer or the alias. Now what happens is that if you don't specify an alias, the name must be put into `[]` so that the parser doesn't recognize this as a variable name, but as column name qualification.